# Underscore.js to check if element in array exists?

Tags: underscore.js

How do I check if the element in the array exists in underscore.js? For example, I have `['aaa', 'bbb', 'cfp', 'ddd']`, and want to check to see if `'cfp'` exists. If it does, I want to show some text. My code below doesn't work and I'm not sure why:

```
<% _.each(profile.designations, function(i) { %>                                                                                        
            <% if (typeOf profile.designations[i] == "cfp") { %>                                                                                         

            <div class="cfp-disclosure-text">                                                                                                           

              <p>Show this text if does exist</p>                                                                                                                                      

            </div>                                                                                                                                       

            <% } %>                                                                                                                                     

            <% }); %>
```

Comment: @torazaburo it's not php i think. sk_225 is just using underscore as template engine.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just use `_.contains` method:

http://underscorejs.org/#contains

```js
console.log(_.contains(['aaa', 'bbb', 'cfp', 'ddd'], 'cfp'));
//=> true

console.log(_.contains(['aaa', 'bbb', 'cfp', 'ddd'], 'bar'));
//=> false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ES6 array `includes`

```
const designations = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'cfp', 'ddd'];

const exists = fruits.includes('cfp');

console.log(exists);
```

or we can use directly

```
console.log(['aaa', 'bbb', 'cfp', 'ddd'].includes('cfp'))
```